# How to create separate snapshots repo in cloudbees

Tags: maven-2, jenkins, cloudbees

We have a CloudBees project with several "jobs". Some of those job correspond to separate Google projects that are updated independently.

Our problem is that all updates go to the same snapshot repo, so we get when two developers A and B are working on the same project and A is pushing his changes, B is getting that latest version, rather the local one he would like.

Ideally we'd like to have one snapshot repo for each Google project, so they don't overlap each other.

How do you create different snapshot repo in the same CloudBees project and associate them to different projects?

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to use different snapshot repos for different projects then you will need to use the "private local repository" feature for each job to ensure that the jobs are pulling the dependencies from their own snapshot repos.

Additionally you will need to provide separate settings.xml to each job as otherwise they will be pulling dependencies from the same remote repository anyway.

You then need to create a separate Maven WebDAV repository in your CloudBees services using the Forge Repositories screen. Note that if you are on a Free tier you may be at the limit for the number of Maven WebDAV repositories... you could cheat! by telling the settings.xml that the repository path is actually a sub-path of the path, e.g. https://user1650693.forge.cloudbees.com/repositories/snapshot/project1 and https://user1650693.forge.cloudbees.com/repositories/snapshot/project2 and not https://user1650693.forge.cloudbees.com/repositories/snapshot

that would essentially mean the project1 and project2 would see completely separate remote repositories.

All this is a lot of work on your behalf.... and a lot of pain to manage.... and when you are doing a lot of work-arounds in Maven that *screams out loud* that you are doing it wrong!

Maybe you need to pause and think where it is that you are invoking the Maven anti-pattern and back away from that anti-pattern.

One anti-pattern I see a lot is running builds past the `verify` phase when you don't understand what you are doing.

In general I recommend that the CI system never runs `deploy` for non-release builds as it screws over developers... [the work-around is to run `deploy` but to a separate -SNAPSHOT repository that is only used by the CI system]

This is why I also favour only going as far as `verify` on the CI system as if you go as far as `install` you will need each job to have its own private maven repository... though sometimes you need to go that far to break jobs up piecemeal.

The rule of thumb is that the developer's machine should have the dependencies that the developer built and not get updates at the random whim of Maven's refresh -SNAPSHOTs every *whatever you configured in your `settings.xml` interval*

Comment: You advice to "only go as far as verify" is very intriguing. But I'm pretty sure it won't work for reactor builds, where you have multiple modules depending on each other.

Comment: If they are in the same reactor, `verify` will work, as it is after the `package` phase where the artifacts are packaged and attached to the reactor. The only issue is some people use plugins that don't understand how Maven works, and those unfortunate people have to go as far as `install`... solution: fix the borked plugins ;-)

Comment: I think there's one more issue: I never saw this feature in the reactor plugin's documentation. Where can I read more about how artifacts are attached to the reactor?

Comment: The reactor plugin is separate from Maven's reactor. Maven's reactor is just the list of projects and their attached artifacts. This list is maintained while Maven builds. When resolving a dependency, the search order is supposed to be: reactor; local cache; remote repos. Prior to Maven 3.x the reactor search required a separate call, so a lot of older 3rd party plugins omit this vital search. Have a look at `build-helper:attach-artifact` for sample code on attaching artifacts from within a plugin

Answer (score 2):

From a maven point of view, in your scenario, B should not depend on A SNAPSHOT if it don't want to get the "last stable version".

You also can isolate your jenkins jobs maven local-repository using "private local repository" advanced option", so that B will only see the last publicly deployed version of B, not the last built one